# How do I spawn a baby villager using commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to spawn a baby villager using the following command:

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Age:-2000000000}
```

But it isn’t working. What is my error?

Comment: Yes, what's your error? Please paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

The command should be `/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {IsBaby:1b}`

Comment: Incorrect. This answer is for Java Edition. The question is for Bedrock Edition.